# How to make table head stay fixed on scroll?

Tags: html, css

I need the header to stay from moving or be fixed, so that it is still visible, but the table data content scrolls.

I've tried `.grdPCO tr th` to be `position: fixed` but it squeezes in all the table headers to the left side and floats off the table.

```css
.grdPCO {
  width: 2000px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grdPCO tbody {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 400px;
  background: #eee;
}

.grdPCO thead tr {
  display: block;
}

.grdPCO thead {
  display: block;
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
}

.grdPCO tr th {
   position: fixed;
}

.grdPCO th,
.grdPCO td {
  padding: 5px 30px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table class="grdPCO">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th>Semester</th>
   <th>Course #</th>
   <th>Capacity</th>
  <tr>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>4</td>
   <td>5</td>
   <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>7</td>
   <td>8</td>
   <td>9</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I expect the th's or the table header to stay fixed so that they always show.

Comment: Change the first row to: `<tr style="position:fixed">` and the second row to `<tr style="padding-top:20px">`. You can obviously rework this with CSS classes, but this is a starting point

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for but it sounds like you just want sticky headers? Eg;

```css
.grdPCO {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.grdPCO tbody {
  background: #eee;
}

.grdPCO thead th {
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
}

.grdPCO th,
.grdPCO td {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 200px;
  border: gray 1px dotted;  
}

.grdPCO tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
scroll down...

<br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br>

<table class="grdPCO">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Semester</th>
     <th>Course #</th>
     <th>Capacity</th>
    <tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
   <td>.</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: This would work I think, except my `th` is in `tbody`, can you edit your answer to do that?

Comment: The `position: sticky` property does not work in IE 11. However, since this browser is no longer supported by Microsoft, it might not be a big deal. It just depends on your particular use cases.

Comment: @Juan th doesn't belong in tbody in a [table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) and if you want the same sticky effect but support IE then @CameronTinker has a point and you'll need some javascript to dynamically add `position: fixed` depending on scroll offsets etc which isn't a big deal.

Comment: Yeah, this html is auto generated using gridviews in asp.net, so I don't know why th is in tbody.

Comment: Any idea how I use javascript to add the `position: fixed` ?

Comment: Ya but that's a pretty broad question to ask someone to write polyfill sticky headers for ya. You might look around on the web first and make some attempts on your own first but it sounds like you're trying to find a fix for something a little more complex than css alone will do your work for. Sorry bud.

Answer (score 0):

Try this only CSS & HTML.

```css
table thead tr {
  display: block;
}

table th,
table td {
  width: 100px;//fixed width
}


table tbody {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto; //set tbody to auto
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>


</table>
```

Comment: This is fine, but I need it with where `th` is in `tbody`